# how do I input javascript created nodes into an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push elements generated from this

```
function myFunction() 
{ 

    var x=document.getElementById("stat"); 
    var para=document.createElement("p"); 
    var node=document.createTextNode(stat.value); 
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element=document.getElementById("output"); 
    element.appendChild(para); 
    stat.value="" 

}
```

into an array to run through 4 separate functions to determine their avg., med., mode, and standard deviation. I thought I'd be about to target them with an getElementByTagName, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your code isn't totally adding up. You state stat.value, shouldn't it be x.value?

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo.

You're using `stat` as a variable name instead of `x`.

The most important thing for a variable it's the name... you should pick variable names more carefully.

Functions have both a name and a semantic and the semantic (logic) is of course more important than the name (not saying that the name is not important, of course).

But variables are basically just names.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function myFunction(element) 
{ 
  var stat=document.getElementById(element); 
  var para=document.createElement("p"); 
  var node=document.createTextNode(stat.value); 
  para.appendChild(node);
  var element=document.getElementById("output"); 
  element.appendChild(para); 
  stat.value="" 
} 

var elements = ['stat', 'stat2', 'stat3', 'stat4']

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  myFunction(elements[i])
}
```